# Which is intended to fetch the results quicker?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Which is intended to fetch the results quicker ?

*Single column data* from 400 tables or 400 columns from a *single table* ?

Comment: What task does accept both solutions? The initial solution should follow the best design practices, not some performance-related delusions

Comment: Most likely the single table but does it matter? What sane person would purposefully design their database to require accessing 400 tables in a single query when they could just access one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 results from one table is definitely faster than 1 result from each of the 400 tables. Think about needing to enter the first 400 phone numbers from the NYC phone book. So you decide to read the first number from phonebook A, the second number from phonebook B, ... , and the last number from the 400th phonebook. It would have been much faster to read them sequentially from the first phonebook (AKA structure your tables appropriately from the get-go).

This is a major problem which will come back and bite many programmers. It comes down to the importance of strategically organizing the structure and layout of your data tables before you get in too deep.

Answer (score 2):

As per my Knowledge fetching data from single table will be faster. If you are fetching data from single table you do not need to specify any joining condition.

If you are having any situation where you want to fetch data from single column you can use the [ColumnStoreIndex](http://blog.aspplatinum.com/) feature of SQL Server 2012.

But I am not sure that this type of indexing is available in mySql or not.

Basically I have posted here the concept of MS SQL server. I am not having much idea about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for sure, but I presume 400 columns from a single table will be quicker!

**Reason :**

> The pointer has to move from each datablock(table) and search for a column.This has to be done for 400 tables.
>
> But the **HIT** level of 400 columns in a single table would be much higher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Single column data from 400 tables", but here is my answer:

If you mean "Is it faster to load 400 rows with one column or 1 row with 400 columns", I would say it's faster to load the latter based on the results in [this blogpost](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/). *That being said,* 400 rows sounds like a maintenance nightmare, and I doubt it would be worth the tradeoff. Maybe you could post more details and we could give you better answers?